# MVC 3 client-side validation without annotation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to have the same kind of client-side validation in MVC 3 without being able to set the validation at the viewmodel level?
I have two requirements that are preventing me from adding my validation at the viewmodel level. I'd like to be able to have the same kind of "built-in" validation but without changing the viewmodel or controller code. I'd like to be able to change, turn on/off, validation at the view level post-deployment. Ideally I'd like to be able to edit the view mark-up without writing and maintaining mountains of my own JavaScript.

Comment: What requirements are those, out of curiosity?

Comment: The requirements are that any of the validation can be turned on/off and thresholds within the validation can be changed. All post deployment without recompiling the back-end.

Comment: Gotcha. I ended up implementing a solution using an IronRuby script engine to handle a similar request, so I didn't have to recompile the app to change its runtime behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own TypeDescriptionProvider which will allow to augment your viewmodel at runtime.

Based on [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2659) code sample (XmlMetadataTypeDescriptor, XmlMetadataTypeDescriptionProvider) you should be able to:

1. Augment viewmodel using external xml which contains validation attributes.
2. Turn on validation with

   TypeDescriptor.AddProvider
3. and turn it off with:

   TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider

**Update**

For more information you can read great article: ["Understanding the TypeDescriptor: A Metadata Engine for Designtime Code"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx).

Comment: Do you have any simpler examples? The example you linked appears to have a corrupted solution file.

Comment: What is the error with solution? as it's working for me. Just keep in mind that you don't need the whole code as its example for RiaServices you need to tailor it for your needs: use only XmlMetadataTypeDescriptor, XmlMetadataTypeDescriptionProvider and dependent classes. If you still have problems I can publish code that I am using.

Comment: Thanks for the help Baal but I can't get the project to compile and it's in a language I don't understand. I'll try and track down and VB.net examples for XmlMetadataTypeDescriptor.

Comment: Oh so you are using VB.net didn't know sorry for that. I will try later publish working code but it will be in C#

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. I'd really like to find a simple or basic example. All the examples I've found thus far are large implementations.

Comment: OK I will try to simplified my project and publish it for you this evening. In the meantime you can read link in updated post.

Comment: the sample link doesn't work.  Does anybody know where we hook into the MVC rendering pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

This may help ya, only validation on the client though so not really ideal.